# Drupal views integration ContactID inserts commas into number

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Within Drupal Views integrations creating a view of contacts, the Replacement Pattern "[id] == CiviCRM Contacts: Contact ID" inserts commas when a contact_id is greater than 999 - surely this is incorrect behaviour? Does anyone have a work around for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pull the contact ID as a field in the view (even before you replace it), to what is the thousands marker field set?  I believe the default setting is comma (see http://screencast.com/t/8tiEiqVOBG ) - you might check that and change it to "none" if that is the case, to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Perfect! Yes that was exactly it, all sorted thanks!

Comment: there has been a long running argument within Drupal Views to stop the comma being default as it affects all such numeric fields.